# How can I have my dash app comment list all the previously inputted comments?

Tags: plotly-dash

I am trying to create a comment section in my dash app where the comments submitted will be updated as new comments are submitted.I tried different ways but it wasn't working.. this is the current code I have now which is able to return the most recent comment submitted.

```
layout = html.Div([
    html.H3(children='Write Comments'),
    dcc.Textarea(
        id='textarea',
        value='',
        style={'width': '100%', 'height': 200},
    ),
    html.Button('Submit', id='button', n_clicks=0),
    html.Div(id='comment-output', style={'whiteSpace': 'pre-line'})
])


# Submit comment through pushing the 'submit' button
@callback(
    Output('comment-output', 'children'),
    Input('button', 'n_clicks'),
    State('textarea', 'value')
)
def update_output(n_clicks, value):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        return 'Submitted Comment: {}'.format(value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the history with the callback and then add to it, otherwise it will just overwrite with the latest. I've tried this locally and it works:

```py
@callback(
    Output('comment-output', 'children'),
    Input('button', 'n_clicks'),
    [
        State('textarea', 'value'),
        State('comment-output', 'children'),
    ],
)
def update_output(n_clicks, value, children):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        return f'{children}\n Submitted Comment: {value}'
    else:
        return ''
```